# knockout.js で サーバからビューに送られたJSONを取得したい。

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sails.js

サーバーでEmployee とういうjsonを作成し、画面表示時に以下のようにデータを画面に渡して、
このdata-employeeをなんとかknockout.jsで取得して、knockout.jsの方でデータを編集したものをeditedListとして画面のテーブルに表示したいですが　このEmployeeのデータをどうやったらknockout.jsの方で読み込めるのでしょうか？

・　HTML

```
<table id="table" data-employee={{ Emplyee }}>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>名前</td>
    <td>苗字</td>
    .
    .
  </tr>
 </thread>
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: editedList">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: secondName"></td>
    .
    .       
  </tr>
 </body>
</table>
```

・　Knockout.js

```
//１.　ここにEmployeeデータを取得する処理

//２.　Employeeデータを使って一覧表示用データを作成する

//３.　２で作成したデータを以下のような感じで画面にバインドする
ko.applyBindings({
    editedList: [
        { firstName: 'Bert', entryDate: 'xxxx-xx-xx' },
        { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'xxxx-xx-xx' },
        { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'xxxx-xx-xx' }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

data-employee には json 文字列として渡し、kockout 側で JSON.parse にすれば良い、という回答なのですが、json の作り方はサーバサイドの言語によって異なります。
何をお使いなのでしょうか？

一例として、rails だとこんな感じになりそうです
(スミマセン。今は手元に環境がないので、イメージです。
raw はサニタイズせずに出力、escapse_javascript は json を文字列化するのに必要なはずです。)

```
# sample.html.erb
<table id="table" data-employee='<%= escape_javascript(raw(@employee.to_json))) %>'>

# sample.js
jsonString = $("#table").data("employee");
employee = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。環境はsailsというnode.jsのフレームワークを使っています。最初htmlにて{{ employee }}としてknockout.jsでvar employee = $("#table").data("employee");とやってobjectが取れることは確認したのですが、そのオブジェクトがJSON.parse(employee)としてもjson にならなくてobjectのままだったので困っていたところです。@user3758624

Comment: json にならない、ということは、{{employee}} で生成される文字列が妥当
な json  になっていない、ということですね。例えば escape されていないとかです。ブラウザの console に表示されているエラー、html に出力されている 文字列を共有してください。より適切な回答が着くと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。今、jsonString = $("#table").data("employee");
employee = JSON.parse(jsonString);とやってみましたらUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0　というエラーになりました。HTML側で data-employee={{ employee }} としてるところにエスケープ処理が必要でしょうか　@user3758624

Comment: 自己解決いたしました。　テンプレートエンジンの方でjsonを指定していなかったのが原因で、$("#table").data("employee")の形で取得できました。